# MySQL - A better way than subqueries

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have the following query:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tb1
WHERE col4=ANY(
  SELECT col1 FROM tb2
  WHERE col2=(SELECT col1 FROM tb3 WHERE col3='php generated string')
  AND col3=(SELECT col2 FROM tb3 WHERE col3='same string as above')
);
```

It works, but it's very slow.  I know there is a much better (and faster) way to do this, but my lack of experience with SQL queries means I'm trying to make this harder than it needs to be.  I've tried using a JOIN, but I don't truly understand how to make that work in this case either.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can the `ANY` subquery return more than one record?

Comment: Yes, and it always does.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that you need to learn how to use `JOIN`. If you ever are matching up values from one column across multiple tables, you should probably be `JOIN`ing the tables together `ON` that column.

```
SELECT tb1.col1,tb1.col2,tb1.col3 
FROM tb1
JOIN tb2
  ON (tb1.col4 = tb2.col1)
JOIN tb3
  ON (tb1.col2 = tb3.col1
  AND tb1.col3 = tb3.col2)
WHERE tb3.col3 = 'php generated string'
```

Comment: I don't think the duplicate `WHERE` clause is needed.

Comment: I think you'd need two separate joins from tb1 to tb3 to check for the two distinct col3 phrases.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli You're right that my query won't return the same results as the OP's query in many situations, but I suspect that mine is actually the right one (until I hear otherwise about the structure of tbl3).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tb1.col1, tb1.col2, tb1.col3
    FROM tb1
        INNER JOIN tb2
            ON tb1.col4 = tb2.col1
        INNER JOIN tb3
            ON tb1.col2 = tb3.col1
                AND tb3.col3 = 'php generated string'
        INNER JOIN tb3
            ON tb1.col3 = tb3.col2
                AND tb3.col3 = 'same string as above'
```

Comment: Jason, it's worth trying both my answer AND Joe's to see how the results are different for your data (if they are).

Answer (score 1):

If the subquery within `ANY` can return more than one record, then rewriting your query as a `JOIN` will result in duplicates.

Use this:

```
SELECT  col1, col2, col3
FROM    tb1
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    tb3
        JOIN    tb2
        ON      tb2.col2 = tb3.col1
                AND tb2.col2 = tb3.col2
                AND tb2.col1 = tb1.col4
        WHERE   tb3.col3 = 'php generated string'
        )
```

and create the following indexes:

```
tb2 (col1, col2, col3)
tb3 (col3)
```